# Ionic bond formation

Tags: bond, ionic-compounds

When two separate pieces of sodium chloride crystals are physically put together, no wonder that they will not fuse with each other.

But I don’t understand why. Ionic bonds are described to be non-directional and bonds should be formed between the sodium ions and chloride ions in the two pieces of sodium chloride crystals.

Why must I melt the two pieces of crystals to fuse them together/ evaporate a solution in which the two pieces of crystals have dissolved?

Comment: If the surfaces are scrupulously clean, atomically smooth and placed in a vacuum, then two separate crystals will probably fuse after being contacted. It'd be a form of [cold welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding).

Comment: @ Nicolau Saker Neto Why is the fusion impossible at room temperature and pressure?

Comment: Consider surface adsorption of molecules of gases and bad alignment of surface ions of the touching crystals.

Comment: Because you need to place the ions less than a nanometer apart, and in ordinary conditions there'd be jagged edges, grime and air in the way.